# MENSAJE A OBJETO PYTHON

Tags: python, lista, objeto

Espero que todos estemos bien.
Escribo porque tengo problemas con mensajes, objetos e instancias.
El problema que no me doy cuenta como resolver el mensaje para asignar el empleado a la lista que tiene el objeto departamento.

Entiendo que al objeto Departamento tengo que identificar la lista de empleados.

El mensaje de error que recibo es:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\\Main.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Main:
File "c:\\Main.py", line 70, in Main
   asignarEmpleados()
File "c:\\Main.py", line 18, in asignarEmpleados
   Departamento.agregarEmpleado(var)
File "c:\\Depart.py", line 15, in agregarEmpleado
   Departamento.listaEmpleado.append(Empleado)
AttributeError: type object 'Departamento' has no attribute 'listaEmpleado'
```

Main.py

```
from Depart import Departamento

listaDep = []  
listaEmp = []

class Main:

    def asignarEmpleados():
        idEmp = int(input('INGRESE EL ID DEL EMPLEADO A BUSCAR EN LA LISTA DE EMPLEADOS.'))
        for elemento in range(len(listaEmp)):
            if (listaEmp[elemento][0] == idEmp):
                var = listaEmp[elemento]
        nro = int(input('BUSCA EL DEPARTAMENTO AL QUE SERA ASIGNADO.'))
        for objDpto in listaDep:
            if(nro == objDpto.numOficina):
                # Departamento.asignarEmpleado(objDpto)  # Mal
                # objDpto.asignaEmpleado(var)   # Mal.
                Departamento.agregarEmpleado(var)
                
    def cargarDepartamento():
        numOf = int(input('INGRESE EL NUMERO DE OFICINA. \n'))
        while (numOf != 0):
            nomOf = input('INGRESE EL NOMBRE DE LA OFICINA. \n')
            cantEm = int(input('INGRESE LA CANTIDAD DE EMPLEADOS QUE TIENE LA OFICINA. \n'))
            objDpto = Departamento(numOf, nomOf, cantEm, [])
            listaDep.append(objDpto)  
            numOf = int(input('INGRESE OTRO NUMERO DE OFICINA. \n'))

    def cargarEmpleado():
            numId = int(input('INGRESE EL NUMERO ID DEL EMPLEADO. \n'))
            while(numId != 0 ):
                nombre = input('INGRESE EL NOMBRE DEL EMPLEADO. \n')
                apelli = input('INGRESE EL APELLIDO DEL EMPLEADO. \n')
                sueldo = float(input('INGRESE EL SUELDO DEL EMPLEADO \n'))
                objetoEmpleado = [numId, nombre, apelli, sueldo]
                listaEmp.append(objetoEmpleado)
                numId = int(input('VUELVA A INGRESAR EL NUMERO ID DEL EMPLEADO. \n'))

    def listarDepartamentos():
        print ('LOS DEPARTAMENTOS CARGADOS SON: \n')
        for objDpto in listaDep:
            objDpto.muestrarOficina()
            
    def listarEmpleados():
        print('LISTA: ', listaEmp)
        
    while True:
        print ('*********MENU*********** \n')
        print ('1_ CARGA     UN     EMPLEADO   AL        SISTEMA.')
        print ('2_ CARGA     UN    DEPARTAMENTO   AL     SISTEMA.')
        print ('3_ MUESTRA LOS EMPLEADOS CARGADOS EN EL  SISTEMA.')
        print ('4_ MUESTRA LOS DEPARTAMENTOSNTO   AL     SISTEMA.')
        print ('5_ ASIGNA UN EMPLEADO A UN DEPARTAMENTO.         ')
        print ('0_ SALE DEL PROGRAMA. \n')
        opcion = int(input('INGRESE UNA OPCION: '))
    
        if opcion == 1:
            cargarEmpleado()
    
        elif opcion == 2:
            cargarDepartamento()

        elif opcion == 3:
            listarEmpleados()
                                
        elif opcion == 4:
            listarDepartamentos()
    
        elif opcion == 5:
            asignarEmpleados()
    
        elif opcion == 0:
            exit()
```

Depart.py

```
from Employ import Empleado

class Departamento:
    def __init__(self, numOficina, nombreOficina, cantEmpleados, listaEmpleado):
        self.numOficina = numOficina
        self.cantEmpleados = cantEmpleados
        self.nombreOficina = nombreOficina
        self.listaEmpleado = []

    def muestrarOficina(self):
        print (self.numOficina, '#', self.nombreOficina, '#', self.cantEmpleados, '#', self.listaEmpleado)

    def agregarEmpleado(Empleado):
        listaEmpleado = Empleado
        Departamento.listaEmpleado.append(Empleado)
        print('LISTA Empleado: ', listaEmpleado)
```

La clase Departamento tiene un metodo agregaEmpleado donde mando el Empleado.  No me doy cuenta como usar el metodo para primero ubicar el objeto. Que creo que si lo tengo, a ese objeto ubicar la lista y recien entonces, asignarle el empleado

Employ.py

```
class Empleado:
    def __init__(self, id, nombre, apellido, sueldo):
        '''Definicion de un empleado.'''
        self.apellido = apellido
        self.id = id
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.sueldo = sueldo
```

Comment: Para empezar... ¿La indentación de tu código es correcta?

Comment: Qué errores tienes?

Comment: @padaleiana Volvi a revisar por las dudas pero si. esta bien.

Comment: @DarkIceDust.  Departamento.listaEmpleado.append(Empleado)
                   AttributeError: type object 'Departamento' has no attribute 'listaEmpleado'

Comment: A los métodos de la clase Main le falta el parámetro `self`. Eso o está mal indentando.

Comment: @CandidMoe. Perdon. me equivoque cuando subi el codigo. si estaba mal identado. Ahora lo correg'i. Por favor, podr'ias mostrarme, qu'e es lo que debo agregar? porque no me doy cuenta. gracias.

Comment: Si ya "está resuelto", ¿por qué no lo pones como respuesta? ¿En qué difiere la solución que mencionas con la respuesta que ya tiene esta pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que distinguir entre atributos de clase y de instancia: Un atributo de clase pertenece a la clase, y sólo existe una vez por clase.

Un atributo de instancia pertenece a un objeto en particular de esa clase. Cada objeto tiene su propio atributo.

Mira este código:

```
class Demo:
    lista_de_clase = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
    def __init__(self, valores):
        self.lista = valores
```

La clase `Demo` tiene un atributo de clase (`lista_de_clase`), que se reconoce por estar inicializado fuera de los métodos.

También tiene un atributo de instancia (`lista`), que se reconoce por ser inicializado en `__init__` y que se usa con `self.` por delante.

Veamos como funciona:

```
a = Demo([1,2])
b = Demo(['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(Demo.lista_de_clase) => ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
print(a.lista_de_clase) => ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
print(b.lista_de_clase) = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
```

Los atributos de clases son accesibles usando el nombre de la clase (`Demo.lista_de_clase`), incluso si no has creado ningún objeto de esa clase.

También puedes acceder al atributo usando un objeto de la clase, tal como si fuera un atributo de instancia.

Los atributos de instancia son distintos para cada objeto:

```
print(a.lista) => [1, 2]
print(b.lista) => ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Entonces, el error que recibes se debe a que `Departamento` no tiene un atributo de clase `listaEmpleado`; lo que tiene es un atributo de instancia. Eso es lo correcto, pues cada depto tiene su propia lista de empleados.

El código tiene errores de sintaxis, la versión corregida puede ser:

```
def agregarEmpleado(self, Empleado):
    self.listaEmpleado.append(Empleado)
    print('LISTA Empleado: ', self.listaEmpleado)
```

Todo método de clase debe tener por primer parámetro `self`, que es el objeto mismo, y que sirva para acceder a sus atributos.

Comment: No, no es asi. Mi error es que estoy enviando al objeto un mensaje que apunta a un atributo que no existe en la clase. Si uso la solucion que tu propones, self + otro parametro hace que haya un atributo extra y da otro error. Est'a resuelto y buscando el proximo problema. Muchas gracias. a todos. – 
Mauricio Luis Vega
 hace 6 minutos